# PyCharm JavaScript import

Tags: javascript, http, http-status-code-404, pycharm

In PyCharm, when I put jquery-1.10.2.js into the main directory and do

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

I get the error "GET /jquery-1.10.2.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -

What is the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

Put the file into a folder called 'static', and

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```